# In C++, How to safely create a file if it's not exist, but not to open it if it's exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

If I directly using `ios::out` to open a file, then it will overwrite it or modify it if the file was existed.

But if I check if there is a file named "XXX" with `ios::in`, and create it with `ios::out` if it's not exist, the file "XXX" may be created by another program during this period, then the file "XXX" will be overwrote or be modified just like the first case.

How can I safely create a file with `fstream` in C++?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no platform-independent way of accomplishing that.

Comment: There is no C++ way of doing so, but every platform I am aware of offers a way to achieve that through platform-specific way. I suggest you retag your question to appropriate platform (I guess 'windows') and rephrase it to ask for platform API, not C++ api.

Comment: @SergeyA Considering that `std::fopen()` is the (adopted) function from C, that's true for C++11 (as tagged by OP) but not anymore for C++17.

Comment: @Scheff correct, but we have to respect the tags, don't we?

Comment: I was a little disappointed to learn that there is no C++ way to do so, which I think is a common feature.

Comment: @xxhxx C++ is OS agnostic.  Anything that deals with the "OS" ("system") is mostly not supported and you need a library, or call the OS specific API functions to do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

A proper solution to your problem in the C++ standard library is **only available since since C++17 - not in C++11** (and in the C standard library since C11):

`std::fopen` (and C's [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)) now allows you to use the subspecifier `x` which forces the function to fail if the file already exists (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen)

> File access mode flag "x" can optionally be appended to "w" or "w+" specifiers. This flag forces the function to fail if the file exists, instead of overwriting it. (C++17)

Comment: Directly contradict's OP's tag of C++11.

Comment: @SergeyA Nevertheless, it's a nice catch (I didn't know about). Future readers may find this article valuable although it's tagged C++11. ;-) (I did.)

Comment: A C++11 (and earlier) solution would be to write (or find) a custom `std::basic_filebuf` class that uses platform APIs directly so you can provided the necessary flags when opening the file (ie, calling `CreateFile(CREATE_NEW)` on Windows, which fails for an existing file), and then construct a `std::istream` object using that class.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for everyone.

In C++23, we can use `std::ios::noreplace` to accomplish this  operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using microsoft C++ you can do the following:

```
    std::fstream file;
    bool ok = file.open("path_to_my_file", std::ios::app, _SH_DENYWR); // open the file in non sharing write mode
    if (ok)
    {
     // you now have exclusive access to the file
    }
    else 
    {
      // try later (for instance)
    }
```

This is not standard C++ but this will ensure whoever opens the file first will get it and will not erase any existing content (ios::app)

Comment: `_SH_DENYWR` only denies write access, not read access.  For exclusive access, you would need to use `_SH_DENYRW` instead

Comment: Thanks  @RemyLebeau, but my understanding of the question is that in case the file does not exists the OP wants to ensure the process that tested for its existence can write into it in an atomic way. Once the file is open, knowing if someone else previously created it is a matter of checking if its lenght is 0.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid overwriting, use **ios::app** when writing to an existing file to append your new data to it instead of overwriting it.

Comment: But I want not to write to it if the file was exist.

Comment: But the question is about the thing, that is exactly opposite to your answer. It is about creating a file if doesn't exist, and not opening it, if it does exist.

Comment: If the file already exists, then I would like to create it with another file name.

Comment: use `ios::app` will also modify the file, which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps i haven't understood your question clearly.